# Как отключить импорт модуля во время выполнения Python скрипта?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется загружаемый в `.NET` приложение скрипт через `PySharp`.

В `.NET` приложении объявлен класс и проброшен в `Python` скрипт.
Далее в скрипте пишется клиентский код с использованием этого класса (классов).

В связи с тем, что бы не допускать ошибок и облегчить написание клиентского кода, человеку который ничего не знает о реализации `.NET` приложения, требуется описать как минимум данные классы в виде модуля и импортировать его при написании кода.

Что бы каждый раз не приходилось отключать данный модуль вручную, как это сделать динамически?